# Accessing Tomato router in bridging mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, tomato, bridging

I've flashed my Linksys WRT54GL router with the Tomato 1.28 firmware.  This has worked fine, and I set its IP address to 192.168.1.2.  I already had a wireless router, but the reason I bought this Linksys router was to give my old PC (which had no network card) access to the network, so the router was to act as a bridge between the existing wireless router and the old PC (the old PC *does* have a NIC with ethernet port).

Anyway, I needed to set the router up in 'wireless ethernet bridge' mode, and set the SSID and security settings to match those of the existing router, which I have done.  It worked fine and the PC had internet access... but then I decided to change the Tomato router's IP to 192.168.1.1 - this was a bit of a mistake.  :-)

Because the existing wireless router already had an IP of 192.168.1.1, I now get its web interface when I access that IP in the web browser instead of the Tomato interface.

Can anyone think of a way I can get back into the Tomato interface to set its IP back to 192.168.1.2?  Presumably once they have different IPs, I will again be able to access the web interface of both routers on the two different IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off the existing router (and any other nearby wireless things), the Tomato should show up again (on 192.168.1.1).

Comment: For some reason it didn't work; I turned off the existing router and tried to connect to the Tomato router and I just got a connection timeout.  Perhaps the Tomato routing table already had that IP address down as being for the original router?

Comment: @Jez, that could be it; maybe try resetting the tomato? I don't know enough about the situation to offer more specific advice, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the other WLAN, connect a machine directly to it using a cable, set that machine manually up so that it resides on the same network. You should then be able to communicate with it.

You **might** have to reset it, so that it comes up with default config.